# Input/Output file names

Tags: input, filenames, output, ifstream, ofstream

I want the output file to have the same name as the input file (with different extension)
E.g: Input: packet_a.raw , Output: packet_a_data.txt

I tried saving the fileName in a string but ifstream and ofstream do not accept a string.
I tried using char[] but then I have a hard time modifying it.

Comment: `std::string` has `c_str()` method, which returns a `char[]` with the string's content. Notice, however, that you **MUST NOT** modify the contents of the array returned by `c_str()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is where libraries pay off.  Have a look at the Boost [filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#basic_path-inserter-extractor), or your IDE's platform library (e.g., MFC).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `char[]` and then modify it by `sprintf`. Something like that:

```
ofstream outFile_raw;
ofstream outFile_txt;
std::string  data;

std::string format_raw="raw";
std::string format_txt="txt";

char fileName[20];
sprintf(fileName, "..\\Packages\\packet_a.%s", format_raw);

outFile_raw.open(fileName, ios::trunc);

if(outFile_raw.is_open())
{
     outFile_raw<< data; // Write contents of the data to the file stream.
     outFile_raw.close();
}

sprintf(fileName, "..\\Packages\\packet_a.%s", format_txt);

outFile_txt.open(fileName, ios::trunc);

if(outFile_txt.is_open())
{
     outFile_txt<< data; // Write contents of the data to the file stream.
     outFile_txt.close();
}
```